# How to get a precisely accurate size in mm on a printed paper using CSS

Tags: html, css, printing

Suppose I need to have an output of an image to be equal exactly `40mm x 50mm` on a printed paper. **CSS** for the picture is `img { width: 40mm; height: 50mm; }`, however upon measuring the actual printed size it turned out to be slightly bigger (for example width is about ~41-42mm). Is it possible and if so, how to define CSS to match the printed output?

Comment: This sounds like a printer issue not a css one. You have specified the size in mm in the css but the printer is not accepting that size. Frankly though worrying about a 1mm difference is hardly worth it.

Answer (score 0):

You misspelled the `height` in the question but let's hope you didn't in the CSS. :)

Also, try this and let's see if it works:

```css
@media print {
  img {
     width: 40mm; 
     height: 50mm; 
  }
}
```

Comment: yep, CSS in a source file is correct. I thought @media print { img { } } vs img { }  makes no difference, it's going to take a while to confirm it.